# How do I send BTC from my wallet to another wallet?

Tags: wallet

I have BTC in my bitcoin.com wallet, but I have no way to use it in Texas, so I want to send it to family, but I need assistance on how to send BTC from my existing bitcoin.com wallet to another family member's wallet.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a custodial account (a service which controls your keys/coins). If so, you’ll have to ask their customer service to help you.

Comment: I have a hard time following your problem description. Could you please elaborate what service you are using and what options to interact are available to you?

Comment: No, the site does not control anything.  It is BTC I sent to myself by accident and I just want to send it to another wallet?  I have been in contact with them, but no answer has been given, so I was told to ask here for useful advice.

Comment: I am using Bitcoin.com for now.  I have been using them all year.  I have asked  many operators because I want to use the BTC before it is lost.

Comment: There should be a "Send BTC" options in your wallet, and your recipient can generate an address and you can send to that address.

Comment: Questions can be reopened by addressing the issues which other contributors identified. It seems you want to know the general process for sending Bitcoin money to another person. (which involves asking the other person to send you a QR-code or another form of their "receiving" Bitcoin-address - you then instruct your wallet to use that QR-code/adddress as the recipient).

Comment: The receiver sends me the wallet and I put the wallet in the destination wallet, but I put my own wallet by accident, so the Bitcoins are in my wallet.  I want to send the BTC from my wallet to another wallet.  That is the question I am trying to ask.  

Is sending from my wallet to another BTC wallet a 
"general process" question?  Forgive me for being new to this, but I am trying to learn from other users.  Thanks to all fort the questions, suggestions, anything because I want to know more and those suggestions give me more information to learn.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance.  I am asking the operators of the BTC wallet.  I think I was not asking the right question,  I hope I got the right question to ask from here.  I will try to be back with an answer that I need.

Comment: On the site with my BTC, they have a "2 Factor authentication" that does not accept the password, and it asks me to enter the code, but they do not send me a code?  I have to ask them for help with this.